# Using JFileChooser with LWJGL

Tags: java, image, file-io, lwjgl, jfilechooser

I am trying to use `JFileChooser` with `LWJGL` but `fileChooser.isDisplayable()` returns false, I checked because It wouldn't pop up.

This is what I am using,

```
private void chooseFile(){
    choose = new JFileChooser();
    choose.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
    choose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    choose.setFileFilter(new FileFilter(){

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            if(f.isDirectory()){
                return true;
            }
            final String name = f.getName();
            return name.endsWith(".png");
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "*.png";
        }

    });
}
```

So if anyone has experience with this or just generally knows why it shouldn't couldn't or would never work or what ever tell me, So I can go on with my life and find some other solution, or fix it if anyone knows how to.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). *"Thanks infront, rose."*  Don't include sigs. in questions.  They are noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never tell the JFileChooser to open a dialog. You need to call `fileChooser.showOpenDialog()` or one of the other dialog methods (can be open/save/etc.).

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJFileChooser.htm) is a simple example.

Comment: I thought you had to select a parent frame to call it, but using `fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)` seems to work so far thanks.

Comment: You can set a parent frame for it, but setting it to null will create a frame for it. Glad I could help!

Comment: I have had an error where upon the file viewer losing focus, the pane would be gone and inaccessible. Looking it up, it appears that is what happens when you set the dialogue to null. Do you have any clue how to go about fixing that @RobWagner